# Strong Flickering

Tags: rendering

Whenever I make shiny objects and render them then this flickering occurs. I don't know what could cause the problem, I thought that adding glare could make it, but even after removing glare, the problem is still there. It's the most visible on the rings of the bag.

I would like to upload the file but it's about 500 MB, but I don't know how to do it here https://blend-exchange.com/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF5YZoDwDYI&t=317s

This video explains everything - setting clamping - direct and indirect light to 10 will remove the flickering/ glittering.